# Restricted notions of set-theoretic geology

Tags: set-theory, forcing

We say that $W$ is a ground of $V$ if $W$ is a model of ZFC and there is a poset $P$ such that $W[G]=V$ for some $G$ which is $P$-generic over $W$. The Ground Axiom ($\mathrm{GA}$) asserts that $V$ has no nontrivial grounds while $\mathrm{DDG}$ is the statement: for all grounds $W_1,W_2$ of $V$ there is a ground $U$ (of $V$) contained in $W_1\cap W_2$.

It has already been proven that $\mathrm{GA}$ can be forced (by means of a class forcing notion) and that $\mathrm{DDG}$ is a theorem of ZFC. I'm interested in restricting these notions. For example, $\mathrm{GA}_{\sigma\text{-closed}}$ is the assertion that the universe in not a set-forcing extension of an inner model by a $\sigma$-closed forcing notion.

Similarly $\mathrm{DDG}_{\sigma\text{-closed}}$ is the statement: for all $\sigma$-closed grounds $W_1,W_2$ of $V$ there is a $\sigma$-closed ground $U$ (of $V$) contained in $W_1\cap W_2$.

Of course, $\mathrm{GA\rightarrow GA}_{\sigma\text{-closed}}$. How about the converse? Are there models of ZFC satisfying $\neg\mathrm{GA+GA}_{\sigma\text{-closed}}$ or $\neg\mathrm{GA+GA}_{ccc}$? This question arises from https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609270.pdf and when it was published the questions were still open.

Moreover, I'm not able to exhibit models in which

1. $\mathrm{DDG}_{\sigma\text{-closed}}$ fails,
2. $\mathrm{DDG}_{ccc}$ fails.

The last two questions are probably easier. Thanks to everyone who wants to take part in this interesting discussion.